# find a file in a folder using a bash script (linux)

Tags: linux, bash

1. need to create a text file within the folder (done)

I use nano to create a file called spn.txt and input some data inside. (done)

```
4:3
5:5
1:5
3:1
4:3
4:1
```

2. create a script

   2.1. ask user to input the name of the text file (txt) in the folder

   2.2 find the txt file

   if there no file found
   ask user to input the name of the text file (txt) in the folder

   2.3. if have the file read the value of the file and display the number of the left hand side

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "please input file name with extension (e.g spn.txt)"
read filename
```

how to create a while command that

look for the filename

if filename not found in the folder, ask user to input file name

if file name is found. display the number of the left hand side.

Comment: Some examples: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-while-loop/

Comment: What did you try, when trying to "look for the filename", and how did it fail? The same question applies for all the other steps: A Stack Overflow question should be about a specific place you got stuck, not a request for someone to write a program for you.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this does not define a loop and hence maybe does not answer your question.

This said, if you need to quickly manage some user interactions you can try [Zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/3.32/file-selection.html.en)

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=`zenity --file-selection --title="Select a File"`

case $? in
         0)
                echo "\"$FILE\" selected.";;
         1)
                echo "No file selected.";;
        -1)
                echo "An unexpected error has occurred.";;
esac
```

Obviously, you need Zenity to be installed, which can be a problem regarding the portability. The advantage is that you can create "complex" input forms. It all depends on your context.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=""

echo -e "\nStarting script ... You can press Ctrl+C anytime to stop program execution.\n"
    
##### Ensure the user will provide a valid file name #################    
while [[ ! -r "${filename}" ]] ; do
  echo -n "Please, enter the file name: (e.g spn.txt): "
  read filename
done

#
# At this point we have a valid filename supplied by the user
# So, prints the left values of it, using the ':' as a field delimiter
cut -d':' -f 1 ${filename}
```

The cut command is used above with the following parameters:

-d':'  -> Set the delimiter to ':'

-f 1   -> Display just the field number 1. If you would like to display just the right numbers, you could use -f 2 here, because assuming the field delimiter is the character ':', the right numbers are located on the second field.

Answer (score -2):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
###   Maintainer: Vrej Abramian, Git: https://github.com/vrej-ab, vrejab@gmail.com    ###

### Configuration Parameters Start ###
request_filename_message="Please input file name with extension (e.g spn.txt): "
filename_variable='filename'
attempts_count='3'
_file_check='' # Leave this empty
### Configuration Parameters End ###

### Finctions Start ###
# Unified messages
echo_green(){ echo -en "\033[0;32m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0;0m"; }
echo_yellow(){ echo -en "\033[1;33m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0;0m"; }
echo_red(){ echo -en "\033[0;31m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0;0m"; }

# Promt and request to input a valid `filename`
request_filename_function(){
  # Use `read` with `-p` option which will prompt your message and 
  # avoid using extra `echo` command.
  read -p "${request_filename_message}" "${filename_variable}"
}

# Check if the inputed filename is accessible
file_check(){
  if [ -r "${!filename_variable}" ] ;then
    echo_green "\n[INFO]: ${!filename_variable} - file is available."
    _file_check='pass'
  else
    echo_red "\n[ERROR]: ${!filename_variable} - file is either un-available or un-accessible."
    _file_check='fail'
  fi
}

# If provided `filename` wouldn't be available, this provides retrying chances
retry_function(){
  local i=1
  while [ "${_file_check}" != 'pass' ] && [ ${i} -lt ${attempts_count} ] ;do
    echo_yellow "\n[WARN]: Please tray again - $(( attempts_count-i )) times left!"
    local i=$(( ++i ))
    request_filename_function
    file_check
  done
  if [ ${i} -gt ${attempts_count} ] ;then
    echo_red "[FATAL]: No more attempts, Bye-Bye...\n"
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Get the provided file's first column data - assuming that the delimiter is a ':' character in the file
left_handside_numbers_function(){
  cat "${1}" | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
}

# Filter the user defined param,eters in this script
defined_parameters_function(){
  defined_parameters=$(sed -n '/^### Configuration Parameters Start ###/,/^### Configuration Parameters End ###/p' "${0}" | \
          grep -v '^\#' | awk -F'=' '{print $1}')
  defined_parameters="${filename_variable} ${defined_parameters}"
}

# Run cleanup jobs
cleanup_function(){
  unset ${defined_parameters}
}
### Functions End ###

### Script Body Start ###
request_filename_function
file_check
retry_function
left_handside_numbers_function "${!filename_variable}"
defined_parameters_function
cleanup_function
### Script Body End ###


exit 0
```

Comment: Answers should be narrowly focused on the question at hand (a "question" that's too broad to have a specific, narrow answer shouldn't be answered at all -- see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). There are parts of this that are arguably responsive, but they're hidden inside a huge mess of boilerplate, most of which isn't related to anything the OP asked.

Comment: Shaikh Ralib, Did you get a chance to test this solution? Please let me know if you had difficulties understanding or running it.